# Combine separate Excel sheets which having chart figures in tabs using Python

Tags: python

Able to combine Excel sheets into one. But figures which are stored in tabs after  combining showing as empty. Please help how to overcome this. I used Win32 too but it's not working, with that I am not able to insert back to Excel!

A scenario based explanation is appreciated?

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'', engine='xlsxwriter')
wb=writer.book
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
words=["Plot","Graph","Chart","plot"]
for filename in glob.glob(r"C:\Users\*.xlsx"):
#excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
workbook=excel.Workbooks.Open(filename)
(_, f_name) = os.path.split(filename)
(f_short_name, _) = os.path.splitext(f_name)
f_short_name=f_short_name[:6]
for sheets in workbook.Worksheets:
    if any(word in sheet_name for word in words):
        #for sheet_name in workbook.Worksheets:
        for i,shape in enumerate(sheet_name.Shapes):
            if shape.Name.startswith('Picture'):
                shape.Copy()
                image=ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
                imgdata=io.BytesIO()
                wks=wb.add_worksheet("{0}_Plot".format(f_short_name))
                image.save(imgdata,format='PNG')
                wks.insert_image(2,2,'',{'image_data':imgdata})
    else:
        df_excel = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet_name)
        df_excel.to_excel(writer, f_short_name+'_'+sheet_name, index=False)
```

writer.save()
TypeError: argument of type '_Worksheet' is not iterable

Comment: maybe provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will allow people to build further on your example

Comment: I have couple of excel files file1 and file 2. want to combine two workbooks to one. But my workbook have sheets with chart figures and tables. While combining tables were able to retrieve but not the figures...figures tabs showing empty.

Comment: Anybody...Had idea on this use case, please revert